# Create number of inputs (with prefix) based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a dynamic number of number inputs based on the number that I enter in a first input. Per example, if I enter "3", it should create 3 rows:

row1------(input)
row2------(input)
row3------(input)

The input is entered here:

```
  <tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Cantidad de arreglos:</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><input type="number" id="cantidadArreglos" onchange="espacioArreglos(this.value);" size="1"></td>
  </tr>
```

On changing the number of this input, the function "espacioArreglos" should be called and generate a number input for each row.

How can I do this? My function does nothing upon changing the value of the input "cantidadArreglos".

```
  function espacioArreglos() {
  for(var i = 0; i <= cantidadArreglos; i++)
  {
    var cantidadArreglos = document.getElementById('cantidadArreglos').value;         
    var tb = document.createElement('input');           
}
}
```

Comment: where do you want the rows? in a textarea or in html?

Comment: Where is the source code for your `espacioArreglos()` function and what part of creating dynamic elements are you having problems with? This isn't a free writing service so I recommend you show the source code for that function and explain what you have tried so far. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I will show it right now. I thought its something super general and simple so you wouldn't need more code :)